# Checking multiple columns for one value with greater than or equal (>=)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, query-optimization

Let's say i'm having a table like this:

```
id,col1,col2,col3,col4
```

I wish to check if any of col1,col2,col3,col4 are greater than or equal 10

The idea was smth like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (col1 >= 10 OR col2 >= 10 OR col3 >= 10 OR col4 >= 10);
```

Is there any more optimized way?

I thought that I could use IN, but as don't have any clue how to use >= in it.

Comment: I don't think there's any simplification. Maybe you should normalize your data.

Comment: Why is it not optimal? You cannot use `IN` operator for this purpose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming none of the values are `NULL`, you can use `greatest()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE GREATEST(col1, col2, col3, col5) >= 10;
```

This is no more efficient, but it is shorter.

Comment: sorry my comments tonight, but shouldn't it be `GREATEST()` ? ;)

Comment: @eshirvana . . . Yes.  Now that it is morning, I see that you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

That is how I might write the script.
You could try the below, but performance is likely to be degraded (not sure as don't have MySQL setup)

**Test Table Setup**

```
 CREATE TABLE tbl_test (
 col1 INT
 ,col2 INT
 ,col3 INT
 );

INSERT INTO tbl_test (col1,col2,col3)
VALUES (10,15,20)
,(1,2,3)
,(4,5,6)
,(10,0,0)
,(20,0,0);
```

**Comparing using GREATEST()** (Less verbose, but performance cost likely)

```
SELECT *,GREATEST(col1,col2,col3)
FROM tbl_test
WHERE GREATEST(col1,col2,col3) >= 10;
```

**Performance Optimized Version** (More verbose, but improved performance)

For performance reasons, I'd generally recommend separate queries instead of multiple OR statements. This allows database engine to use optimal indexes (should they exist)

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_test WHERE col1 >=10
UNION
SELECT * FROM tbl_test WHERE col2 >=10
UNION
SELECT * FROM tbl_test WHERE col3 >=10;
```

Comment: as you mentioned , the union will be faster if there is separate index on every and each column , otherwise it's going to suck and actually worse.